# How To Save datagridview image column in sql server 2008 database using WinApp C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

In my project I'm using a DataGridView with 32 columns of textbox and 1 column as Image column . My question is how to insert the DataGridView image column to the database (sql server 2008)?
I've written same codings below but it doesn't work. Showing error message.

My coding is :

```
memorystream stream = new memorystream();
string filename=datagridview1.Cells[33].Value;
bitmaps image=new bitmaps(filename);
image.Save(stream,system.Drawing.Imaging.Imageformat.Jpeg)
byte[] pic=new byte(image);
```

Comment: Error Mssage : Invalid Column Range. (Shows at 2nd Line Of the Coding)

Comment: then you have to check if you have a column 33

Answer (score 0):

from the comment I thing your datagrid view don't have a 33 column and you got the exception `Invalid Column Range` because you passed the Max lenght exist in your datagrid in `datagridview1.Cells[33].Value` (use `step by step` debugging to chek column in your Datagrid)

**update :**

and you must set the index of row you want to use (index of the row)

```
string filename=datagridview1.Rows[index].Cells[33].Value;
```

or if you you want use the crrent row you can use

```
string filename=datagridview1.CurrentRow.Cells[33].Value;
```

Comment: SORRY MY ERROR MESSAGE IS : Parameter is not valid.